# Parsing html to listboxitem

Tags: c#, listbox, html-parsing

What is the best way show html tags in a listbox item...for example i have this tag and i want to parse it to listboxitem Content property:

```
"<font color=\"blue\">123456789<br><font color=\"black\">This book tells the story of her life from A to Z. <br>"
```

The final result must be "123456789" in blue color and "This book tells the story of her life from A to Z." in black.

Comment: You can use htmlagilitypack.

Comment: i have used this but it didn't worked: ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(_entity.Definitions[0].Text);
itm.Content = doc;
lstWords.Items.Add(itm);

Answer (score 1):

```
string html="<font color=\"blue\">123456789<br><font color=\"black\">This book tells the story of her life from A to Z. <br>"  
      string anchorPattern = "<font.*?>(?<val>.*?)"<.*?"
                        MatchCollection mresultSet= Regex.Matches(html, anchorPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
             for (int at = 0; at < mIcerik.Count; at++)
                 {
                                mVal= Convert.ToString(mIcerik[at].Groups["val"].Value).Trim());
        ....
```

Comment: thanks but it's not always in same format sometime formats are different...i just want to show it in it's right html format like how they will be in a proper html page, not just extract their text.

Comment: to see what result must be go to this website and enter the html code: http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Comment: then you should see htmlagilitypack.